# Wifi callback not called in launch daemon

Tags: ios, objective-c, daemon, jailbreak, nsrunloop

I want to write a launch daemon in iOS which connects to networks programmatically. For connecting to networks, I'm using [Cykey's (David Murray) WifiManager app](https://github.com/Cykey/wifi). Before writing the daemon it worked perfectly (I have used it in a springboard tweak) but now it doesn't scan for available networks (the method `- (void)_scanDidFinishWithError:(int)error` isn't been called). By logging, I found that the method `_scan` in DMNetWorksManager is called but the `static void DMScanCallback(WiFiDeviceClientRef device, CFArrayRef results, int error, const void *token)` isn't called. I think it's because of the runloop I have in the main.m file. Here is my code:

**main.m:**

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {           
        // insert code here...
        MSManager *server = [[MSManager alloc] init];

        //start a timer so that the process does not exit.
        /*NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:now
                                                  interval:.01
                                                    target:server
                                                  selector:@selector(start)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:NO];

        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [runLoop run];*/
        [server start];
        CFRunLoopRun();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the start method in **MSManager.m**:

```
- (void)start
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(managerDidFinishScanning)
                                                 name:kDMNetworksManagerDidFinishScanning
                                               object:nil];


    //Some other code here....
}
- (void)managerDidFinishScanning
{
    //Do some work here
}
```

**NOTE:** Iv'e used both CFRunloop and NSRunLoop (commented in the code) but none of them worked.